# How to start learning flute?

Tags: self-learning, flute

I would love to learn and play with flute.  Could you suggest me some introductory books or websites for the beginners, and also what brand of flute is good for beginner (less than 300 dollars…)?

Comment: Lots of votes to close - no explanations. Welcome but this site isn't here to recommend what you ask. When you read the 'Help centre', you'll appreciate why.

Answer (score 1):

Find a teacher, who will likely be able to give a recommendation, where a flute can be rented first. Even if you find the teacher approach too costly in the long term, you will at least start correctly instead of wasting time by cultivating wrong approaches. I'm more than sceptical, whether the price limit is reasonable, even for a used instrument.

Comment: 300 dollars...from which country..?